# Le « langage de programmation exotique » : mais encore ?

Tags: usage, terminologie, informatique, comparaison-de-langues

On a le [*langage de programmation **exotique***](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_de_programmation_exotique) et on indique que l'adjectif *exotique* est employé afin de « distinguer ces langages de ceux communément utilisés dans l'industrie. » (Wikipédia) Le *TLFi* parle de l'adjectif, aux associations fréquentes, et indique « par référence au pays ou à la culture propres du locuteur » avec comme sens « généralement lointain ou peu connu; qui a un caractère naturellement original dû à sa provenance. ». [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/exotique/32204/difficulte) semble indiquer que l'idée de pays lointain ne fait pas partie de l'idée en soi, mais on n'indique pas ce qui en ferait alors partie. Par ailleurs on a l'adjectif *ésotérique*, comportant plusieurs acceptions par extension et métonymie, on a même le langage ésotérique, n'étant « compréhensible que des initiés ; hermétique, abstrus, abscons » ([*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9sot%C3%A9rique/31011); voir aussi [*Ac.9*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/%C3%A9sot%C3%A9rique)).

En anglais, on a le [***esoteric*** programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language), lié à l'article en français. On trouve des définitions de nature comparables à celles en français pour cet adjectif ([*AHDotEL*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=esoteric&submit.x=0&submit.y=0), [*Merriam Learners*](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/esoteric)) : l'enseignement au groupe restreint, ce qui est difficile à comprendre, ce qui est limité à un petit groupe etc. Le lexique et l'usage peuvent différer, dans l'une ou l'autre langue.

---

Un langage qui sert de référence dans cette catégorie est [INTERCAL](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL) dit-on (« [Abandon all sanity, ye who enter here](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/) » ; « It is a well-known and oft-demonstrated fact that a person whose work is incomprehensible is held in high esteem », du manuel original). On a aussi des langages avec des propriétés particulières, comme [*Befunge*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge), une « tentative de définir un langage aussi difficile à compiler que possible » (« This was attempted with the implementation of self-modifying code [...] and a multi-dimensional playfield [...] », dit l'[article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge) en anglais). On comprend qu'usuellement certains langages de programmation exotiques soient plus ésotériques que d'autres (on dit *Malbolge* : « Un langage conçu pour être le plus difficile à programmer et pour être le plus ésotérique possible. »). Reste qu'il est difficile (et peu intéressant), à mon avis, de comprendre ce qu'est un tel langage quand on le définit par opposition à ceux communément utilisés dans l'industrie (il faut une expertise dans le domaine) et en utilisant pour ce faire un adjectif plus ou moins porteur.

---

- Pense-t-on que l'adjectif *exotique* en français pour le *langage de programmation exotique* convienne ou non ; *ésotérique* eût-il été meilleur ; et surtout, pourquoi/pourquoi pas ?
- A-t-on un meilleur terme technique, plus précis ? La sémantique associée à la catégorie est-elle surchargée au point où l'on doive ajouter des
  précisions, un autre adjectif à *langage de programmation exotique* ?
- Quel(s) autre(s) choix s'offrent-ils le cas échéant pour exprimer intelligemment en quoi ces langages consistent à des gens du public (qui ne sont pas spécialistes) autrement que par une extrapolation (le public ne connaît pas son pays d'origine ici) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Les langages de programmation exotiques* sont qualifiés exotiques pour dire qu'ils sont très originaux par rapport aux langages usuels.

---

### Première question

### Pourquoi pas le terme ésotérique?

*Ésotérique* réfère à l'[*ésotérisme*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9sot%C3%A9risme/31012), qui est en français l'ensemble des pratiques obscurantistes, occultistes (et autres choses bizarres). L'ésotérisme n'est pas nécessairement exotique, il s'agit de pratiques sociales obscures aux non-initiés et dédiés aux personnes qui y croient, comme la voyance.

La pratique d'un langage de programmation n'entre pour le moment pas dans la cadre d'une pratique obscurantiste, aussi bizarre que soit le langage.
De plus, de part la culture française, ésotérique a acquis une connotation soit fortement positive, soit négative, qui peut nuire à l'utilisation de ces langages.
Dans tous les cas, le sens de ésotérique ne colle pas.

### Pourquoi le terme exotique

Le terme *exotique* est beaucoup plus proche de ce qu'on veut dire que *ésotérique*. On pourrait aussi utiliser *original*, qui colle parfaitement en terme de sens, mais peut avoir une connotation légèrement négative, comme si il était trop bizarre pour être compris.

*Exotique* transcrit bien le concept d'originalité, avec une légère connotation positive liée à sa nouveauté, et une approche innovante et agréable.

---

### Deuxième question

Exotique ne fait pas seulement référence à ce qui vient d'un pays étranger. On peut le trouver utilisé dans des circonstances qui n'ont rien à voir par rapport aux origines géographiques : [Matière exotique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mati%C3%A8re_exotique)

Comme dit plus haut, on peut utiliser original, c'est la même chose, mais avec un peu moins de panache et de saveur (au sens figuré) : on peut presque dire "en moins sexy".

Un autre [exemple](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1273570Auw&bvm=bv.131286987,d.d2s) d'utilisation courante du mot *exotique* dans le sens de *original* (dans le jeu LoL)

---

### Troisième question

Cette question me semble être une extension de la deuxième, je n'ai pas grand chose à rajouter.

Comment: C'est intéressant mais ça laisse en suspend la question de savoir pourquoi en anglais on utilise *esoteric* (ésotérique) et pourquoi en français on utilise *exotique*.

Comment: Je n'ai pas traité la raison de l'utilisation du terme *esoteric* en anglais car je n'en ai pas les compétences, et surtout parce que ce n'était pas demandé et que ce n'est pas le sujet de FrenchLanguage de traiter de terminologie anglaise. Ce qui importe, c'est le sens qui est donné à  *esoteric programming language*. D'après l'article fourni en exemple, voilà la signification de *esoteric* : "The use of esoteric distinguishes these languages from programming languages that working developers use to write software."

Comment: On peut également entendre le terme *hermétique*, qui peut s'appliquer à des langages volontairement difficiles à comprendre au point d'être quasiment impossible à utiliser (comme le Spoon ou le Malbolge), mais pas à des langages utilisables qui se fondent sur un principe novateur.

Comment: @Anne Aunyme En effet, le terme *hermétique* est très intéressant pour décrire ces langages. J'aurais spontanément utilisé *abscons* et *fermé* pour les qualifier, mais hermétique me semble au moins aussi clair.

Comment: @AnneAunyme je pense que le "brainfuck" rentre dans cette catégorie: le langage est volontairement très compliqué à lire, et seule une machine est capable de l'interpréter (ou un humain qui a du temps à perdre...).

Comment: @Random: en effet, mais comme je connais des gens qui prétendent le contraire j'ai préféré éviter le débat en prenant des exemples indiscutables.

Comment: Je pense que les termes *"abscons"*, *"fermé"*, *"hermétique"* et j'ajouterais *"sibyllin"* décrivent quelque chose de **volontairement** difficile d'accès. Un langage de programmation *exotique* est juste un langage peu utilisé, pas (nécessairement) un langage difficile d'accès.

Answer (score 1):

L'adjectif *"exotique"* dénote principalement la rareté. Le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/exotique) le définit comme :

> Qui est relatif, qui appartient à un pays étranger, généralement lointain ou peu connu; qui a un caractère naturellement original dû à sa provenance

Je ne pense pas me tromper en disant que l'utilisation de quelque chose d'*exotique* a donc un caractère *inhabituel* ou *original*. Et un language de programmation exotique n'est rien d'autre que cela : un langage de programmation auquel on ne pense pas immédiatement. L'environnement, l'habitude, l'expérience conditionnent chez nous des réflexes comme le choix d'un langage de programmation. Un langage *exotique* c'est un peu l'outsider, celui qu'on n'attendait pas mais qui peut se révéler beaucoup mieux adapté au problème qu'il faut résoudre.

Évidemment, la définition d'*exotique* varie selon le milieu. Par exemple, le FORTRAN est considéré comme exotique partout sauf dans la communauté scientifique qui l'utilise encore beaucoup.

Puisque je parle de science, *"exotique"* est un terme tout à fait approprié en chimie pour décrire une réaction chimique ou un composé chimique "peu utilisé", mais qui trouve son utilité.

**Différence avec l'anglais** :

Certains termes en français et en anglais sont de "faux amis" pour celui qui parle l'autre langue. Dans ce cas précis, *"esoteric (en)"* n'a rien à voir avec son équivalent français et on ne peut pas dire une *"réaction ésotérique"*. En revanche, *"exotic reaction"* décrit très bien une *"réaction exotique"* en chimie, et *"exotic programming language"* devrait être compris par la plupart des anglophones, même si ce n'est pas l'expression la plus usuelle.

HTH

Comment: Je ne sais pas de quels langages tu parles mais, pour moi, aucun langage de programmation n'essaye d'être compris que par env. 0.25% de la population, bien au contraire ! Sinon ce n'est pas un langage de programmation, c'est juste une langue morte !

Comment: Un langage *exotique* n'est en général pas un langage *"cryptique"* ou *"sibyllin"*. S'il l'est, le côté *"cryptique"* ou *"sibyllin"* l'emporte sur le caractère exotique. Le plus secret l'emporte sur le reste !!