# Le « two-dimensional fungeoidal » et la « visuospatial syntax » : dimensionnalité ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, terminologie

Il existe un spécimen de poisson exotique, pour ainsi dire, [*Fish*](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) (><>), puisqu'il s'agit d'un de ces [langages de programmation exotique](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/21760).<sup>1</sup>

---

[image]

<sup>Capture partielle d'écran de l'interpréteur en ligne *fishlanguage.com* (de *Suppen*)</sup>

---

Tout comme [*Befunge*](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), une de ses particularités est d'être un « two-dimensional fungeoidal », ou d'avoir une « two-dimensional toroidal topology » et on dit aussi qu'il possède un « two-dimensional playfield » ou un « two-dimensional instruction pointer ». Il est lui aussi un [*langage réflexif à pile*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge). On dit par ailleurs que "les extensions et variantes de *Befunge* sont appelées « [Fungeoids](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fungeoid) » ou simplement des Funges" et on lie sur Wikipédia ce dernier terme à un plat cuisiné de l'Angola (!). Heureusement [en anglais](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge#Etymology) on trouve plutôt une référence à une racine fictive de fongible (*fungible*) et plus généralement, on a des références aux « metric spaces » et aux « coordinates », et on semble ranger ce type d'idée dans celle de « [visuospatial syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language) ». Je veux pouvoir discuter d'un langage de programmation exotique de ce type en français.

---

- Comment rend-on le langage qui est un *two-dimensional fungeoidal* ?
- De quel type de [dimensionnalité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dimensionalit%C3%A9) parle-t-on pour les langages qui
  ont cette caractéristique généralement sans en avoir exactement deux (dimensions) ; ou a-t-on un autre concept ici ?
- Plus généralement parle-t-on de syntaxe « visuospatial » en ajoutant
  un *e* ou on utilise un autre terme ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Mais il vaut mieux ne jamais sous-estimer l'[utilité](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz#Programming_interviews) de l'exotisme ([exemple](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/6kRZb4L5vXzfYxdNf)).</sub>

Comment: Je ne comprend pas la première question ? Est-ce « Comment rend-on un langage two-dimensional fungeoidal ? » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avant propos : Le sujet de la question est complexe et requiert des compétences dans des domaines autres que le français, je doute que tout le monde ait pu comprendre ce qui était demandé. Je réponds avec ce que j'ai réussi à comprendre et t'invite à consulter des personnes plus compétentes dans le domaine pour affiner les réponses.

---

### Première question

Si j'ai bien compris, on cherche une transcription en français de l'expression *two-dimensional fungeoidal*.
L'adjectif two-dimensional se traduit trivialement par **bidimensionnel**.

Quant à l'adjectif *fungeoidal*, après recherche, je n'ai pas trouvé d'équivalent en français. Il existe alors deux façons de contourner le problème :

1. Inventer un terme à partir d'un mot de la même famille.

La racine *fung-* de *fungeoidal* et *Funges*, d'après les éléments apportés dans la question, semble venir des adjectifs *fungible* (*fongible* en français).

On peut donc calquer le construction de *fungeoidal* sur l'adjectif *fongible* pour donner **fongeoïdal** (masculin singulier, donc sans *-e*), avec le *e* après le *g* pour conserver la prononciation \ʒ\.

PS :

2. Recherche un synonyme dans la langue originale et le traduire.

D'après les éléments fournis dans la question et ce que j'ai pu trouver et comprendre du langage sur wiki (notamment sur le déplacement du pointeur d'instructions qui évolue dans un environnement torique), on peut utiliser les adjectifs *toroidal*, que l'on traduit par **toroïdal** ou **torique**

Trois traductions possibles :

- toroïdal bidimensionnel
- bidimensionnel torique
- fongeoïdal bidimensionnel

---

### Deuxième question

Cette question, même si elle requiert une terminologie, relève plus des mathématiques que du français.

Commençons donc par détailler le sens de *dimension*

Les dimensions dont ont parle ici sont celles de l'algèbre vectorielle (NB : Ne pas confondre avec la définition de l'*analyse dimensionnelle* dans la [page](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dimensionalit%C3%A9) fournie en exemple dans la question, il ne s'agit pas de la même chose).
Les trois dimensions de l'espace (hauteur, largeur, profondeur) en sont un exemple.
Dans les langages courants utilisés en entreprise, la liste des instructions défilent dans une seule direction (au [sens mathématique](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/direction) (def 13)). Des fois les instructions sont répétés et des fois sautées, mais le programme défile comme si toutes les instructions étaient inscrites sur une droite sur laquelle un curseur défile.

Ces langages sont **unidimensionnels** car peuvent être représentés sur une droite. Les langages plus complexes en terme de parcours sont **multidimensionnels** quand leur dimension est entière et supérieure ou égale à 2, **fractales** ou **à dimension fractale** quand leur dimension est non entière.

---

### Troisième question

Je n'ai pas réussi à trouver assez d'éléments pour répondre à cette question, concernant la signification du terme *visuospatial syntax*, des détails sont à apporter dans le sujet.

Je note juste que j'ai vu apparaitre le terme **visuo-spatial** (qui s'accorde en genre et en nombre, donc **syntaxe visuo-spatiale**) sur des recherches Google, dans les domaines médicaux de l'optique et de la neurologie. Il semble que ce soit un terme acquis de l'anglais, il pourrait tout aussi bien être aussi repris ici, mais mérite d'être expliqué pour éviter que chacun mette ce qu'il a envie de comprendre derrière ce mot.

Comment: D'accord, je n'avais pas tout compris. Juste pour information, il est bien important de comprendre ce qu'est un environnement torique quand on parle d'une surface plane (car c'est un point clé du langage que tu dois présenter). Il s'agit d'une surface plane, finie (c'est à dire avec une surface finie) mais sans bord, comme si les bord opposés étaient collés. Si, par exemple, on sort par le bord supérieur, on revient par le bord inférieur (comme dans le vieux jeu Snake). Quand on demande au pointeur d'aller plus à droite qu'il ne peut le faire dans le script du langage, il réapparait à gauche.